# VFP6 Com DLL not working in vs2012 .net framework 4.5 MVC 4 web application

Tags: .net, visual-foxpro

I am using a COM DLL (type library) created using vfp6 in my MVC 4 application for data manipulation with FoxPro DB data-tables. I can able to register the dll successfully using Regsvr32 and also can able to do references in my project.

In my web application i can able to create an object for the class of COM dll but not able to access its properties or methods. I got `iisexpress.exe has exited with code -`1073741819 (0xc0000005) access violation`error when run the project from visual studio(admin mode) with debug. If i run the project without debug i got "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))` exception.

```
Dim objCOM = new foxprocom() // this creats the instance without any issue

objCOM.Path = "my path" -- this line throws the errors
```

Earlier i used the COM dll which was created using vfp9, that works fine but this version using vfp6 is not working. Is vfp6 COM dll compatible with .net 4.5?

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Might that be a 32 bits issue? Be sure your target platform is x86. OTOH there are a lot of reasons for getting C0000005 error, most of which were corrected until VFP9. I assume you already imported the typelib. Did you also test, if that DLL works succesfully say with VB6 or a JScript?

Answer (score 0):

You might do well to ask this question in the support/user forum at West Wind Technologies web site. There are many users there who have worked with FoxPro and .Net together, especially the notable Rick Strahl who is a master at this kind of stuff.

http://support.west-wind.com/

Comment: *You should go somewhere else to ask* might be a comment to the original question, but it is absolutely **never** an appropriate answer here. This space is for writing an **answer** to the question asked and nothing else.

Comment: Fair enough. I did not realize the distinction between the two, but I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no. Years ago I ran into issues with VP6 .dlls no longer working on Server 2008 - Server 2003 worked just fine. The issue is with more recent versions of IIS and COM object permissions. I would highly recommend using VFP9 to build your COM .dll, a lot has changed with how COM objects perform security clearances through Component Services since VFP6. Regsvr32 will register your .dll into the registry, but that is no longer enough. Using Component Services, you need to create a new COM application and then add your compiled .dll and .tlb files as a new component. You can then assign a "user" account and password to your COM object to ensure that it has read/write access to any directories and databases that you need. Also make sure you right click Foxpro9 and select Run as Administrator before you compile your dll.